# javascript onclick function not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do an onclick event where when a light bulb image is clicked it goes from a light bulb off to a light bulb on image and vice versa.
I am using an external javascript file. when I click on the image nothing happens.

I cant figure out whats wrong,

my html portion:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/program-01.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/program-01.js"></script>
    <title>
        <h1>Program-01</h1>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="LightOff">
        <img src="images/light_off.png" id="light_off" alt="" onclick="LightBulbFunction()" />
    </div>
</body>
```

my js file function:

```
function LightBulb() {
    var image_change = document.getElementById("light_off");

    if (image_change.src == "images/light_off.png") {
        image_change = "images/light_on.png";
    } else {
        image_change = "images/light_off.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: does `onclick` work outside of a `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions/Problems:

1. You function names are different.

   You're using the function `LightBulbFunction` on the `onclick` event. But, you don't have the function of that name in your script. You'll get

> ReferenceError: LightBulbFunction() is not defined.

2. To change the image `src` attribute value, use `image_change.src` inside the event handler.

To solve the problem change the name of `onclick` attribute value to `LightBulb`.

```js
function LightBulb() {
  var image_change = document.getElementById("light_off");

  if (image_change.src == "images/light_off.png") {
    image_change.src = "images/light_on.png";
    //          ^^^^
  } else {
    image_change.src = "images/light_off.png";
    //          ^^^^
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="LightOff">
  <img src="images/light_off.png" id="light_off" alt="" onclick="LightBulb()" />
  <!--                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
</div>
```

Better approach will be to use `addEventListener` to bind events on the elements.

```js
document.getElementById('light_off').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var image_change = document.getElementById("light_off");

  if (image_change.src == "images/light_off.png") {
    image_change.src = "images/light_on.png";
  } else {
    image_change.src = "images/light_off.png";
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="LightOff">
  <img src="images/light_off.png" id="light_off" alt="" onclick="LightBulb()" />
  <!--                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
</div>
```

Comment: even after making the changes you showed, its still not working for me. I didnt try the addEventListener, just made the .src and function name changes. My js file is external so Im wondering if somehow i have messed up something else as well. I checked the file location of js file and images and every thing seems right. Is there something else i could be doing wrong?

Comment: @kronis72 Looking at your code, only above two problems can be seen, did you change the `function` name. Any error on `console`?

Comment: im running on my machine as a localhost, so I had to at some more information to the img src on the js file....http://127.0.0.1:8020/itse1311/program-01/ when I add that it seems to work but when i upload it to the server, it does not work, not does images/light_off.png

Comment: but when i upload it to the server, it does not work, nor does images/light_off.png..... the folder my index.html is saved theres a folder called images and inside that, is the actual image. I dont understand why its not working with just that img src file location

Comment: @kronis72 Make sure the path of the images is correct, images are having right permissions, check browser console for errors

Answer (score 0):

Well in your html, the code is `onclick="LightBulbFunction()"` while in javascript it is `LightBulb`. Change either of them and make them match

Answer (score 0):

You are not redefining the `.src`. Change

```
image_change =
```

to

```
image_change.src =
```

And your function needs to have the same `LightBulb` function name.